# When I set the Viewcontroller is the root navigation controller, I recieve the found nil error

Tags: swift, appdelegate, viewdidload

When I set the ViewController is the root navigation controller in the file `Appdelegate.swift`, like this:

```
var viewcontroller=ViewController();
var rootnavigationcontroller=UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewcontroller);
self.window?.rootViewController=rootnavigationcontroller;
```

Then I configure the ViewController like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadLaunchScreen();
        Initilize();//Here configure the MapView parameters;
    }
```

Then in the function `Initilize();` I receive the error that means the `MapView` has found nil.

But if I do not set this Viewcontroller as the rootnavigationcontroller in the `Appdelegate.swift`, I will run well.

I want to ask why and how to solve it?

Comment: is your`@IBOutlet` connected ?

Comment: are you using storyboards

Comment: I used @IBOutlet to connect, and also use the storyboards

Comment: You do not need `;` in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using storyboards then try this

```
    let stroyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "storyboardname", bundle: nil)//nil if its not out of your project
    let ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourstoryboadid")
    var rootnavigationcontroller=UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewcontroller);
    self.window?.rootViewController=rootnavigationcontroller;
```

above problem can happen when you use storybords and you are instantiate the viewController not from storyboard thats when your outlet found nil because is is not bounded to the outlet

if you are not using storyboards then your code is perfet

Answer (score 0):

If you are not adding `rootnavigationcontroller` then your `ViewController` code will not be executed. So you will not get any error. For successfully MapView implementation, bind your MapView `@IBOutlet` in storyboard or XIB.

Comment: But there is also a lot of other compenents,MapView is just an example, I tried ,but others will show the same error。